# get list of all React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have defined many React components like this:

```
class ComponentOne extends React.Component {
    static someCustomMethod() {
        console.log('hello from ComponentOne');
    }
    ...
    render() {
        ...
    }
}

class ComponentTwo extends React.Component {
    static someCustomMethod() {
        console.log('hello from ComponentTwo');
    }
    ...
    render() {
        ...
    }

}

class ComponentThree extends React.Component {
    static someCustomMethod() {
        console.log('hello from ComponentOne');
    }
    ...
    render() {
        ...
    }
}
...
...
class ComponentTen extends React.Component {
    static someCustomMethod() {
        console.log('hello from ComponentTen');
    }
    ...
    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to get list of all React Components in order to be able to call `someCustomMethod()` within each.

This dummy example shows what I need to do:

```
let list_of_react_components = someFunctionToGetListOfAllReactComponents();      // My question is about how could I implement this function to get list of all React Components
list_of_react_components.forEach((react_component, index)=>{
     react_component.someCustomMethod();
});
```

How could I get list of all React components so that it can work like mentioned in this example?

Comment: This is an awfully strange way to design code. What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell?oldformat=true